# except specific name in regular expression in nodejs

Tags: regex, node.js

I want to pass all URL except /employers/ in app.get() of NodeJs. I've wrote as follow but not success.

```
app.get('/(!employers)/*', function(req, res, next) {
   // COME HERE EXCEPT EMPLOYERS
});
```

Comment: Simple `if` condition with `indexOf` is enough, RegEx is not needed. `If (url.indexOf('employers') !== -1) {}`

Comment: I don't want to go another level after app.get(). I want to add in app.get(....) level.

Comment: Try this regEx - ^((?!employers).)*$

Comment: @HarpreetSingh can u post as answer?

Comment: yes sure, but is it working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
app.get(/^((?!employers).)*$/, function(req, res, next) {
   // COME HERE EXCEPT EMPLOYERS
});
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rT3eT4/1)

Comment: To only *match*, you could make the group non-capturing: `(?:(?!employers).)*$`, but why use a regex at all? String functions would be much faster in this situation.